# Resetting the Salesforce Marketing Cloud URL Expiration

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, admin

I am trying to reset the URL Expiration timeframe. The Admin/Send Mangement/URL Expiration page notes:

> Adjusting the timeframe to a time that is greater than what is currently set will cause expired URLs to start redirecting to their original address.

I have increased it from 60 days to 730 days.

The link is still expired in the old email.

Does anyone know how long it will be for the change to take effect? or, is there something else that I should be doing to get this to work again?

Note: I have confirmed that my Settings Source is correctly set to Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is saying that the URL expiration applies at a job level, "These configurations are set at the job level. This means the countdown for the expiration threshold for an email's links begins at the deployment time of the email job."

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/url_expiration/

So the changes you have made won't apply to old emails but should apply to sends going forward.

Answer (score -1):

It did apply to the old emails... eventually! It took about 24 hours to fully go into effect.